# Get ul Id from li in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I get the parent id of the parent `ul` from the `li` id?

```
<ul id='ulTask'>    
    <li id='liSubTask1'>subTask1</li>    
    <li id='liSubTask2'>subTask2</li>    
    <li id='liSubTask3'>subTask3</li>   
    <li id='liSubTask4'>subTask4</li>    
    <li id='liSubTask5'>subTask5</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: From where? where is your js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps you...

```
$('#liSubTask1').parent().id();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `$('li').parent().attr('id')` to get the id of the parent element.

**DEMO**

```js
alert($('li').parent().attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='ulTask'>    
    <li id='liSubTask1'>subTask1</li>    
    <li id='liSubTask2'>subTask2</li>    
    <li id='liSubTask3'>subTask3</li>   
    <li id='liSubTask4'>subTask4</li>    
    <li id='liSubTask5'>subTask5</li>  
</ul>
```